# 401 unauthorized error even after all the checks

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern, express-jwt

First check the error
`GET http://localhost:8800/api/gigs 401 (Unauthorized)`

I am following the tutorial this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csUM7yfiaMw) at 1:59:00 you can see that he successfully got the Gig object to Gigs.jsx. I have been trying to do the same and I have been at this for hours now, I tried a lot to figure this out using ChatGPT but this 401 UnAuthorize error just won't go.

here is the code for some files related to the project which will be useful in figuring out the problem.

server.js

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import conversationRoute from "./routes/conversation.route.js"
import gigRoute from "./routes/gig.route.js";
import messagesRoute from "./routes/messages.route.js"
import orderRoute from "./routes/order.route.js"
import reviewRoute from "./routes/review.route.js"
import userRoute from "./routes/user.route.js";
import authRoute from "./routes/auth.route.js";
import uploadRoute from "./routes/uploads.route.js";
import {handleError} from "./errorhandler/errorHandler.js";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import path from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";


const app = express()

dotenv.config();

mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url); // Get the file path of the current module
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename); // Get the directory name of the current module

const connect = async ()=> {
    
    try{
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO);
        // console.log("mongo connection successful");
    }
    catch (error){
        handleError(error);
    }
}


// Custom CORS middleware
const corsMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    const allowedOrigins = ["http://localhost:5173", "http://127.0.0.1:5173"];
    const origin = req.headers.origin;
    if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
    }
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization"
    );
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    next();
  };

//middleware
app.use(corsMiddleware);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use("/uploads", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "uploads")));


app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/conversation", conversationRoute);
app.use("/api/gigs", gigRoute);
app.use("/api/messages", messagesRoute);
app.use("/api/order", orderRoute);
app.use("/api/review", reviewRoute);
app.use("/api/user", userRoute);
app.use("/api/uploads", uploadRoute);

app.use((err, req, res, next)=>{
    const errStatus = err.status || 500;
    const errMessage = err.message || "Something went wrong";

    return res.status(errStatus).send(errMessage);
});


app.listen(8800, ()=>{
  connect()
    // console.log("Backend connected")
})
```

middleware/jwt.token

```
import createError from "../utils/createError.js";

export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) =>{
    const token = req.cookies.accessToken;
    if(!token) return next(createError(401,("You are not authenticated")));
    
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY, async (err, payload)=>{
        if(err) return next(createError(403,"Token not valid anymore"))
        req.userId = payload.id;
        req.isSeller = payload.isSeller;
        next()
    });
}
```

gig.route.js

```
import {
    createGig,
    deleteGig,
    getGig,
    getGigs
} from "../controllers/gig.controllers.js";
import { verifyToken } from "../middleware/jwt.js";


const gigRoute = express.Router()

gigRoute.post("/", verifyToken, createGig);
gigRoute.delete("/:id", verifyToken, deleteGig);
gigRoute.get("/single/:id", verifyToken, getGig);
gigRoute.get("/", verifyToken, getGigs);

export default gigRoute;
```

gig.controller.js

```
import Gig from "../models/gig.model.js";
import createError from "../utils/createError.js";

export const createGig = async (req, res, next) => {
    // console.log(req.userId);
    // console.log(req.isSeller);
    if(!req.isSeller) return next(createError(403, "Only sellers can sell products!"));

    const newGig = new Gig({
        userId: req.userId,
        ...req.body,
    });

    try{
        const savedGig = await newGig.save();
        res.status(201).json(savedGig);
    }
    catch(err){
        next(err);
    }
}

export const deleteGig = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const gig = await Gig.findById(req.params.id);
        
        if(gig.userId !== req.userId) return next(createError(403, "You can only delete your products"));

        await Gig.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
        res.status(201).send("Product deleted");

    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
}

export const getGig = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const gig = await Gig.findById(req.params.id);
        if(!gig) next(createError(404, "gig not found"));
        res.status(200).send(gig);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
}

export const getGigs = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const query = req.query;
        const filters = {
            ...(query.userId && {cat: query.userId}),
            ...(query.cat && {cat: query.cat}),
            ...((query.min || query.max) && {
                price: {...(query.min && {$gt: query.min})}, ...(query.max && {$lt: query.max})}),
            ...(query.search && {title: {$regex: query.search, $options: "i", }})
        }

        const gigs = await Gig.find(filters);
        res.status(200).send(gigs);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
}
```

newRequest.js

```
import axios from "axios";


const newRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8800/api",
  withCredentials: true,
});

newRequest.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("currentUser")?.token;
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error)
);

export default newRequest;
```

Gigs.jsx

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./Gigs.scss";
import { gigs } from "../../data";
import GigCard from "../../components/gigCard/GigCard";
import newRequest from "../../utils/newRequest";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

function Gigs() {
  const [sort, setSort] = useState("sales");
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const minRef = useRef();
  const maxRef = useRef();

  const { isPending, error, data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['gigsData'],
    queryFn: async () => {
      try {
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("currentUser");
        if (!accessToken) {
          throw new Error("User not authenticated");
        }
        const response = await newRequest.get("/gigs");
        console.log(data);
        return response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error("Error fetching data");
      }
    },
  });

  const reSort = (type) => {
    setSort(type);
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const apply = () => {
    console.log(minRef.current.value);
    console.log(maxRef.current.value);
  };

  if (isPending) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error fetching data: {error.message}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="gigs">
      <div className="container">
        <span className="breadcrumbs">Liverr &gt; Graphics & Design &gt;</span>
        <h1>AI Artists</h1>
        <p>Explore the boundaries of art and technology with Liverr's AI artists</p>
        <div className="menu">
          <div className="left">
            <span>Budget</span>
            <input ref={minRef} type="number" placeholder="min" />
            <input ref={maxRef} type="number" placeholder="max" />
            <button onClick={apply}>Apply</button>
          </div>
          <div className="right">
            <span className="sortBy">Sort by</span>
            <span className="sortType">{sort === "sales" ? "Best Selling" : "Newest"}</span>
            <img src="./img/down.png" alt="" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)} />
            {open && (
              <div className="rightMenu">
                {sort === "sales" ? (
                  <span onClick={() => reSort("createdAt")}>Newest</span>
                ) : (
                  <span onClick={() => reSort("sales")}>Best Selling</span>
                )}
                <span onClick={() => reSort("sales")}>Popular</span>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="cards">
          {data && data.map((gig) => (
            <GigCard key={gig.id} item={gig} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Gigs;
```

this code should be sufficient, still, I would be more than happy to provide some more code of a different file not mentioned here.

Thanks in advance.